# using grails flash object and load balancing

Tags: tomcat, grails, cloud

In our application we have used `flash` object to transport data from one controller to another by grails `redirect()`. Does it pose any loss of data/threat since our application is using load balancing and non-sticky sessions (we are using memcached for our own session management mechanism) ? I read the [grails doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/ref/Controllers/flash.html) says it "**stores objects within the session for the next request and the next request only**" ?  Does it mean `flash` is actually using `session` in the background ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you're absolutely right. Flash uses the http session to store stuff so if you're using a load balancer without sticky sessions you shouldn't use flash scope.

Comment: Any more insight/reference ? I need them to convince my people.

Comment: You've already provided a link to the relevant section in the docs that indicates flash scope uses the session, and I couldn't find a great deal else through googling. I guess to prove this to whomever you need to convince, you could do an experiment with a simple page & controller in an environment that has a load balancer. Maybe submit a value from the page, set this in flash scope, and then redirect to the page and try to retrieve it back from flash. If you submitted on instance 1 and land on instance 2, you won't see the value.